# Mapping Integer to String in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, higher-order-functions, swift5

What is the easiest way to map an `Integer` to a `String`?
Here's an array of Integer.

```
let englishIntLiterals: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
```

I want to map the occurrences of each digits to their Nepali equivalent numbers, which is represented as an array of Strings.

```
let nepaliLiterals: [String] = ["१", "२", "३", "४", "५", "६", "७", "८", "९", "०"]
```

I need `1` to be replaced by `१` and so on.
I know there is a work around with functions, but I am looking after a higher order function solution, which I have not been able to figure out with.

Comment: you only need Int from 0 to 9 to be translatable to nepa? if yes you could try an Int extnsion and adding a `toNepa() -> String` function., so that all your Int in this range can be directly accessed as nepa string. 
This is not really clear what you are trying to achieve by "map the occurence". Please precise the context you want to use this translation, e.g. an example of  what you seek

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a fixed locale number formatter to display your integer localized:

```
extension Formatter {
    static let numberNepal: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ne_NP")
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        return formatter
    }()
}
extension BinaryInteger {
    var nepaliFormatted: String {
        return Formatter.numberNepal.string(for: self)!
    }
}
```

---

```
1234567890.nepaliFormatted  // "१,२३४,५६७,८९०"
```

---

```
let englishIntLiterals = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]

let nepaliLiterals = englishIntLiterals.map{$0.nepaliFormatted}  // "१", "२", "३", "४", "५", "६", "७", "८", "९", "०"]
```

Comment: This is the more appropriate answer. I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: Thank you Leo! This method looks more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. I've made a small extension which should do the job that you are looking for. I extend its capability to entertain large as well as negative numbers also.

```
extension Int{

    func toNepali() -> String{
        let isNegative = self < 0
        let number = abs(self)
        let nepaliLiterals: [String] = [ "०","१", "२", "३", "४", "५", "६", "७", "८", "९"]
        if number > 9{
            var s = isNegative ?  "-" : ""
            for i in "\(number)"{
                s += "\(nepaliLiterals[Int(String(i))!])"
            }
            return  s
        }else{
            return isNegative ? "-\(nepaliLiterals[number])" : nepaliLiterals[number]        
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
let englishIntLiterals: [Int] = [-10,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,100]
for i in englishIntLiterals{
    print(i.toNepali())
}
```

Output:

```
-१०
०
१
२
३
४
५
६
७
८
९
१००
```